# Empty debugger with Ada in VSCode (MacOS)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, gdb, ada, vscode-debugger

I am experiencing a weird issue with the Debugger on VS Code, I am following this guide:  https://github.com/AdaCore/ada_language_server/wiki/getting-started but can't make it work at all. I have installed the Native Debug extension, gdb is installed...etc. I have been working with Ada for some time but just thought about starting to debug my projects. I am first trying to make it work with a simple project hello_world, like explained on the guide.

I can start the debugger, but it won't show anything, not the variables or the call stack, nothing - just which breakpoints I did toggle. The controls that allow you to step through the code are also empty, as you can see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJ7dC.png

The content of my launch.json is:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": ".objs/hello_world",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText",
            "preLaunchTask": "ada: Build current project",
        }
    ]
}
```

The rest are also the same than the guide's. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am a bit lost and don't know what to do.

Thank you.

Edit: Just in case, I did it everything from scratch again, same result. Can't achieve to make it work, debugger controls and variable/watch windows are always empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're building the program with debug information?  For example, with `-g -O0`?